# what is the meaning of hibernate inverseJoinColumns?

Tags: hibernate

I understand hibernate @JoinTable annotation, but I don't understand the inverseJoinColumns. What is it used for?

e.g.

```
 @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
 @JoinTable(name = "stock_category", catalog = "mkyongdb", joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "STOCK_ID", nullable = false, updatable = false) },
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "CATEGORY_ID",
                nullable = false, updatable = false) })

 public Set<Category> getCategories() {
    return this.categories;
}
```

Answer (score 22):

From the javadocs, it means:

> (Optional) The foreign key columns of the join table which reference the primary table of the entity that does not own the association

In layman's terms, it is the column of `Category` that will be used as a part of the `JoinTable` relationship between the current  entity and `Category`.

If you don't specify `joinColumns` and `inverseJoinColumns` on the `@JoinTable` annotation, the persistence provider assumes a primary key to primary key join relationship and still store the equivalent *ID* columns for two related entities in the table by default.

Comment: Why do we actually need to define this `inverseJoinColumns` ? Will it make any difference? Can you give a example and explain why we would explicitly require this annotation? The middle table will anyway have the primary key of the both the tables.

Answer (score 2):

For example, we have 2 models: User and Role. The relationship between those 2 models will be Many-to-Many.
User Model:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "user_roles", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();
```

Role Model:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer id;

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Column(length = 20)
private ERole name;
```

The joinColumn attribute will connect to the owner side of the relationship, and the inverseJoinColumn to the other side

Answer (score 0):

InverseJoinColumn is used to customize the column name in the table of the associated class reference variable name. that column act as a foreign key.

Answer (score 0):

`joinColumns:` Assign the column of third table related to entity itself. 
 `inverseJoinColumns:` Assign the column of third table related to associated entity. 
***example:*** say, you have two tables- one is `Mobile`(having fields- `mobileId`, `mobileName`, `mobileColor`) and other one is `Person`(having fields- `personId`, `personName`) where `mobileId` and `personId` are primary keys in the two table. Now, we add the join table annotation inside 'Person' class  like below, 
 [image: join table] , here the `P_Id` refers to the primary key of `Person` class field `mobileId` and `Mob_Id`(where the `inverseJoinColumns` has been used) refers to the primary key of `Mobile` class field `mobileId`. Together these two table creating the third joined table `My_Third_Table` where `Mob_Id` and `P_Id` both acting as foreign key

Answer (score 0):

we dont assign the primary to both tables thats why we need to use inverse join column for that entities.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to use mapping for one-to-many relation using two approches:

1. The first approach is based on adding only a foreign key into existing table. (two existing tables are used)
2. The second approach is based on adding a new table which contains two foreign keys.

For JPA mapping on Java level for the second approach needs to use inverseJoinColumns. But of course, it's possible to use inverseJoinColumns for mapping many-many relation the same way.